# Writing a parser for a Scheme EBNF Grammar

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, scheme

I'm currently writing my own compiler for a scheme subset and have issues with my own recursive descent parser for the grammar. I'm using the chez scheme grammar found here: https://www.scheme.com/tspl2d/grammar.html. The issues come from the asterisks und plus signs. Since asterisks basically mean epsilon rules, I would either need to check if the following token is legal or allow the called non-terminal method to fail and return nothing. I took the second approach and use a vector to save tokens that possibly need to be restored.

Example:

Note: The code to build the AST is still missing

```
bool Parser::definition() {
  if (variableDefinition()){
    consumeTT(); // consumeTemporaryTokens
    return true;
  }
  if (derivedDefinition()){
    consumeTT();
    return true;
  }

  if (checkNext(Tag::LPAR)) {
    if (checkNext(Tag::BEGIN)) {
      while (definition())
        ;
      consumeTT();
      return true;
    }
  }
  restoreTT(); //restoreTemporaryTokens
  return false;
}
```

Is this the right approach? And how am I supposed to handle Errors now, since basically any rule can fail?

Comment: I guess that's why I'd suggest using the first approach (check the next token to see if it is in the  FOLLOW set).

Comment: Pro-tip: write lisp parsers in lisp. Usually it’s enough to call `(read)`

Comment: When you finish your compiler please tell us how you implemented the tail recursion.  About your question, the semantics of the kleene operator is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star.  The kleene operator can be implemented without epsilon rules as well.